# const reversed = (x) => { if (x < 0) { return -1 * reversed(-x); } doesn't this recursive function make in infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, recursion

as x is constant so it is positive or negative.
because we are checking the value of x which is constant, so it doesn't matter if we put a negative sign before it.
so it will cause an infinity loop as x is still positive.

Comment: Your code should not be in the title of your question/

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to rewrite your code for better readability.

```
const reversed = (x) => {
  if (x < 0) {
    return -1 * reversed(-x);
  }
}
```

If we call `reversed` with `x >= 0`, then `reversed` returns `undefined` because of an implicit return in the JS function.
e.g. `reversed(1) // --> undefined`

If `x < 0`, then we return `-1 * reversed(-x)`. `x < 0` -> `-x > 0`.
We already know that reversed called with `x >= 0` is `undefined`, so we get `-1 * undefined` which results in `NaN` (Not a Number).

TLDR:

- x >= 0  -> `reversed(x) -> undefined`
- x < 0 -> `reversed(x) -> NaN`